# Moving all items in array one place back

Tags: c#, arrays

I have an array:

```
string[] inventory = { "empty", "empty", "empty", "empty", "empty"}
```

Later in code, by collecting items "in game", these empty items will change to "item name".
Then, user can use them or remove them from inventory. When user removes some item, i need to move all following items in array one place back. Etc.:

Inventory contains items "a" "b" "c" "d" "empty":

```
string[] inventory = { "a", "b", "c", "d" "empty" };
```

When user removes item "a", items "b" "c" "d" and "empty" must go one place back in array, so new array will be:

```
inventory = { "b", "c", "d", "empty", "empty" };
```

One way to do this could be to save all other items in array to another array and then manually redeclare inventory with changed "position" in array. But what if I have inventory[100] ... is there any other way to do this, without that long redeclaring?

Thank you for help.

Comment: Sounds like you need a `List<T>`, not an array.

Comment: I think a `Queue<string>` would be best suitable for this, a `List<string>` is at least better than using array this way.

Comment: Why not use a `List<string>` or similar collection without a fixed length?

Comment: Queue isn't right for this. It seems like he might also want to keep the list sorted.

Comment: In addition, you cannot remove elements out of band in a queue .... a queue doesn't fit his application where users can remove items from inventory (unless they can only remove the first item...doesn't quite make sense)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create Inventory class which will keep items and act as items enumerator (it will add *empty* items for enumeration but will not keep them in memory):

```
public class Inventory : IEnumerable<string>
{
    private readonly int size;
    private const string emptyItem = "empty";
    private List<string> items = new List<string>();

    public Inventory(int size)
    {
        this.size = size;
    }

    public void Add(string item)
    {
        if (items.Count == size)
            throw new Exception("Inventory is full");

        items.Add(item);
    }

    public void Remove(string item)
    {
        items.Remove(item);
    }

    public IEnumerator<string> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return items.Concat(Enumerable.Repeat(emptyItem, size - items.Count))
                    .GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
Inventory inventory = new Inventory(5);            
inventory.Add("a");
inventory.Add("b");
inventory.Remove("a"); 
var result = String.Join(", ", inventory);
```

Result:

```
b, empty, empty, empty, empty
```

Comment: A possibility is to include a check to prevent `emptyItem` magical string from being added to the inventory.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen also agree, but I'll keep these details to OP implementation. Just wanted to show main idea

Comment: +1 for defining `GetEnumerator` and not your own separate `Join` method.

Answer (score 0):

You can use  `List<string>` for that. 
You won't have a limit of elements. Once you remove one element, other will be kept in order and you don't have to do any reshuffling.

Comment: seems over kill for this, Queue<string> is a easy way of doing this link King King said.

Comment: @N4TKD I am not sure how LinkedList( to be more specific, List<string>) would be an overkill. It will solve the problem. It is fairly intuitive and easy to understand.  Anyway, List was the first thing that came to my mind after reading the description of the problem and would be my solution.

Comment: Linked List is not just List<string> it as the link says "linked list is a data structure consisting of a group of nodes" per the Wiki you linked, it is overkill by far.

Comment: The `List<>` class of the `System.Collections.Generic` is ***not*** a linked list. It is a [resizeable array](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resizeable_array).

Comment: my bad.. Meant List<string>. Thank you for pointing out my mistake :)